# Monitoring ActiveMQ Artemis apart from Jolokia

Tags: java, snmp, activemq-artemis

I hope to monitor ActiveMQ Artemis instances by configuring and using a SNMP connector by means of known Java properties

```
-Dcom.sun.management.snmp.interface=127.0.0.1 -Dcom.sun.management.snmp.port=50000 -Dcom.sun.management.snmp.acl=true -Dcom.sun.management.snmp.acl.file=/app/artemis/.snmp.acl
```

As ActiveMQ instances were monitored, but it does not work -- No error message is reported for Java SNMP properties, but no process is listening the chosen UDP port.

Is still possible to monitor ActiveMQ Artemis this way? And using JMX?

Comment: How are you setting these properties? What JVM are you using? What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using? What is the contents of your `.snmp.acl`?

Comment: You can certainly monitor ActiveMQ Artemis via JMX. See [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#management-via-jmx) for more details on that.

Comment: Did you use these same properties with ActiveMQ "Classic"?

Comment: @JustinBertram Yes,I use the same properties with ActiveMQ "Classic" and an old Java version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The SNMP agent was removed from Java 11](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8071367) so that may be why it's not working for you.

However, you can certainly monitor ActiveMQ Artemis via JMX. See [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#management-via-jmx) for more details on that.

If you just want to keep an eye on metrics you can use a [metrics plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/metrics.html). Using a plugin like the [Prometheus metrics plugin](https://github.com/rh-messaging/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin) would allow you to see exactly what's happening on the broker, set up alerts, etc.